# unresolved reference adapter TabLayout kotlin

Tags: kotlin

l am try to add TabLayout to my app and he has already kotlin navigation drawer . when l am try to add TabLayout code in my main activity class  l had error red line under `adapter` and `setupWithViewPager` , error is `unresolved reference adapter` and `unresolved reference setupWithViewPager` because l used include activity inside main activity .

main activity class

```
package com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.R.id.tabs_main
import com.iraqairoirt.iraqairports.R.id.viewpager_main
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val fragmentAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        viewpager_main.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        tabs_main.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_camera -> {
                // Handle the camera action
            }
            R.id.nav_gallery -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_manage -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {

            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {

            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

main activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <include
            layout="@layout/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

tabs xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             tools:context="MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs_main"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.tabs.*` to your imports and in theory it should fix?
You're not importing so it doesn't have a reference of the include